# The client syncs variable from the server (mirror unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I have a variable on the server, I simply increase it according to deltatime. How can the client when connecting can synchronize that variable and show the text?
sorry for my english, and i'm new to mirror research. many thank :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that updating a SyncVar on each update may led to performance issues.

Add this Component to an object in the scene:

```
public class MyComponent: NetworkBehaviour
{
 [SyncVar(hook=nameof(OnMyVarChanged))]
 public float myVar;

 void Update(){
  if(IsServer){
   myVar+=Time.deltaTime;
  }
 }

 public void OnMyVarChanged(float oldVal,float newVal){
  //DISPLAY myvar on a text field
 }
}
```

Reference: https://mirror-networking.com/docs/Guides/Sync/SyncVarHook.html